# How to conditionally execute something based on previous processed number of rows?

Tags: talend

I want to execute some subjob if the previously processed number of rows are greater than N. To do this, i'm using the following configuration:

[image]

tFixedFlowInput have some rows.
tAggregateRow uses the count function and outputs one row with the number.
tSetGlobalVar then stores this value into a global var that I can check in the Run If connector (In this case, (Integer)globalMap.get("tSetGlobalVar_1") > 3 ).
tMsgBox then shows if the condition is true.

What I would like is to do the same, but in a more elegant way, using the minimum components required. I would like to connect tAggregateRow with the Run If connector directly (or even tFixedFlow) with tMsgBox, but I haven't found a way to refer to the number of rows previously processed without using the output row2.count variable.

How could I do something like this?

[image]

What should I put in the If condition to refer to the tAggregateRow operation result without connecting it to another meaningless component like exposed at the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for any talend component look under outline tab under the left side workspace pane at the bottom. this lists down the properties available via global variables for that component. Some properties like count of records inserted by output components are only available once the component is executed completely (After).

for your case you can try directly using ((Integer)globalMap.get("tFixedFlowInput_1_NB_LINE")) which gives number of lines (after) given by tFixedFlowInput.
[image]

Comment: I know about NB_LINE global variable. So, your answer is right in those cases where the component stores this variable. But I still want to know if it is not possible to retrieve the number of lines processed by a component that doesn't have this variable, using a "Run If" connector and retrieving it elsewhere. (In the example, from the count operation result in tAggregateRow)

Comment: Unfortunately not, by design; Talend component I/O interfaces are limited to streaming vectors (the data) and global variables (the signals). But this is not a real fatal, since every component, unless it's really poorly coded, should have a NB_LINE var at least

Comment: Thanks! I understand now a little better how Talend TOS works